# Test whether the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (n!)^n/(n)^{4n}$ diverges or converge.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've found this series in my calculus's book

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}$$

But the correct form is 
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n^{4n}}
$$
My question is: How to verify if $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (n!)^n/(n)^{4n}$ diverges or converges? Is it possible?

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) may help you.

Comment: Have you tried the root test?

Comment: I have, but I had some doubts in the moment of evaluate 
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} $

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}}=\frac{n!}{n^4}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\ldots$$